# Should object be explicitly deleted after removing it from a Vector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a `Vector v`  that contains 100 objects of class `Scenario` which is composed of 10 different types of objects.In order to permanently delete `Scenario` and all its objects at index 5 of Vector v , which one of the following is correct way.

```
1.   v.removeElementAt(5);
```

OR:

```
2.   Scenario s=(Scenario) v.elementAt(5); 
     v.removeElementAt(5);
     s=null;
```

OR:

```
3.   Scenario s=(Scenario) v.elementAt(5); 
     s.makeAllObjectsNull();//explicitly assign null to 10 objects inside Scenario e.g. object1=null object2=null and so on
     v.removeElementAt(5);
     s=null;
```

Comment: If the `Scenario`'s objects are not referenced anywhere else and `Scenario` is set to null, all the objects are marked to be garbage collected, since you can't access them anymore anyway. Explicitly setting each object to null does more or less the same thing, albeit with more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does an object need to be explicitly deleted after deleting it from a Vector?
>   in simple word, all object that haven't any reference from another object is legible to be `GC`.

So any case of your code get that condition, then the object will be `GC`.

for example if a Scenario object has only referent from that vector, then:

```
v.removeElementAt(5);
```

the only reference has gone, and it will be legible to be `GC`.

another thing to tell here.
when you doing this:

```
 Scenario s = (Scenario) v.elementAt(5); 
 v.removeElementAt(5);
 s = null;
```

You just declared another reference `s` and then set it to `null`, so it's not necessary to this.

Answer (score 3):

You never explicitly delete an object in Java. The garbage collector *may* automatically free an object's memory when it is no longer [reachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability). Usually you don't have to think about it, other than:

- Some objects hold external resources other than memory. Those must be disposed of explicitly, sometimes through the [java.io.Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface.
- *Unintentional object retention* can occur if a variable outlives the useful lifespan of the object to which it refers. In these cases, it can be useful to set the object to null. But these are the exception.

> **"Nulling out object references should be the exception rather than the norm.** The best way to eliminate an obsolete reference is to let the variable that contained the reference fall out of scope. This occurs naturally if you define each variable in the narrowest possible scope." -- *from "Effective Java," 2nd ed., by Joshua Bloch.*

### For your specific case:

> Let's say I have a Vector v that contains 100 objects of class Scenario which is composed of 10 different types of objects.

Note that your vector does not contain objects. It contains references to objects. There may be other references to the same objects.

> 1.
>
> ```
>  v.removeElementAt(5);
> ```

This removes the *reference* to the object from the vector. The object is eligible for collection if no other references to it remain.

> OR
>
> ```
> Scenario s=(Scenario) v.elementAt(5); 
> v.removeElementAt(5);
> s=null;
> ```

This has no value. It assigns an additional reference and promptly forgets that reference. Setting a single reference to null does not cause object disposal. The object is eligible for disposal if and only if there are no other external references.

> OR
>
> ```
> Scenario s=(Scenario) v.elementAt(5); 
> s.makeAllObjectsNull();//explicitly assign null to 10 objects inside Scenario e.g. object1=null object2=null and so on
> v.removeElementAt(5);
> s=null;
> ```

This is also unnecessary.

You don't have any objects inside the Scenario object. You may have *references* to objects. The garbage collector is looking for *unreachable* objects. It can handle disconnected graphs of references.

If the Scenario itself becomes unreachable, then setting its fields to null has no effect on the reachability of the objects referenced by its fields.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your case.

If u have no more links on scenario object and vector is a storage for your scenarios, then you can just remove it from collection and garbage collector remove it and its children elements from memory. **It is the case of aggregation**

If scenario is stored in some other storage and vector is used to associate your scenario with some other information (but scenario is stored under some other entity), then removing from vector means remove just association between your scenario and some info. Then scenario will stay in your system with all state. **It is the case of composition**